# Inverse of product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n>m$ and let $A$ and $B$ be $m\times n$ and $n\times n$ matrices. $B$ is invertible.

If $A$ is square (*i.e.* $n=m$) and invertible, then obviously
$$
\left(ABA^T\right)^{-1} = A^{-T}B^{-1}A^{-1}
$$
But, if $A$ is not square, can we say something (assuming that $ABA^T$ is invertible)?

Comment: Isn't $(ABA^{T})^{-1}$ in term of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Is $ABA^T$ supposed to be invertible?

Comment: @GabrielR. Yes..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $ABA^T$ is invertible then $A(BA^T(ABA^T)^{-1})=I_m$, that is, $A$ is right-invertible. Similarly $A^T$ is left-invertible with left-inverse $(ABA^T)^{-1}AB$.

Write, abusing notation, $A^{-1}$ and $A^{-T}$ for the right- and left inverses respectively, and $C$ for $ABA^T$. Then $C^{-1}=(C^{-1}AB)B^{-1}(BA^TC^{-1})=A^{-T}B^{-1}A^{-1}$: the same formula holds true.

Comment: Your proof seems correct but I do not think it is completely correct.

For instance, $A= [1,2,1,0,0; 0,1,2,0,0] $ and  b= diag(1:5), gives $c^{-1}$ = $[0.2059, -.1471; -.1471, .1765] $  and $A^{-T} B^{-1}  A^{-1} $ gives [0.2347 , -0.1735; -0.1735, 0.2007] which are clearly not the same.    Do you know why?

Comment: The problem with this answer is that right-inverse for $A$ is not unique. The formula is true for *some* right-inverse, but it is not necessarily the Moore-Penrose one.

Answer (score 12):

I am going to give an answer only for a *symmetric positive definite* $B$.

In this case **the answer** is

$$
(ABA^{\rm T})^{-1} = A^{+ \rm T} B^{-1/2} XB^{-1/2}A^+,
$$
where
$$
X = I-B^{-1/2}(I-A^{+}A) \big( B^{-1/2}(I-A^{+}A)\big)^+
$$

and ${}^+$ stands for the Moore-Penrose inverse.

---

One **way of derivation** is as follows.

Denote

$$
F = B^{-1/2}, \quad \quad G = I-A^{+}A, \quad \quad H(\alpha) = \Big(A(\alpha I +FF)^{-1}A^{\rm T}\Big)^{-1}.
$$

Note that

$$
(ABA^{\rm T})^{-1} = \lim_{\alpha \to 0} \Big(A(\alpha I +FF)^{-1}A^{\rm T}\Big)^{-1} =  \lim_{\alpha \to 0} H(\alpha).
$$

Use [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) to rewrite $H(\alpha)$ as

$$
H(\alpha) = \Big( \frac{1}{\alpha}AA^{\rm T}-\frac{1}{\alpha}AF(I+\frac{1}{\alpha}FF)^{-1}\frac{1}{\alpha}FA^{\rm T}\Big)^{-1} .
$$

Note that $AA^{\rm T}$ is invertible and use Woodbury matrix identity again to obtain

$$
H(\alpha) = 
\alpha (AA^{\rm T})^{-1} - (AA^{\rm T})^{-1} AF \Big( -(I+\frac{1}{\alpha}FF) + \frac{1}{\alpha}FA^{\rm T}(AA^{\rm T})^{-1}AF \Big)^{-1} FA^{\rm T} (AA^{\rm T})^{-1},
$$

$$
H(\alpha) = \alpha (AA^{\rm T})^{-1} + (AA^{\rm T})^{-1} AF \Big( I+\frac{1}{\alpha}F \big(I - A^{\rm T}(AA^{\rm T})^{-1}A \big) F \Big)^{-1} FA^{\rm T} (A A^{\rm T})^{-1}.
$$

Note that

$$
A^{\rm T} (A A^{\rm T})^{-1} = A^+, \quad \quad I - A^{\rm T}(AA^{\rm T})^{-1}A = G = G^2,
$$

and rewrite $H(\alpha)$ as

$$
H(\alpha) =\alpha (AA^{\rm T})^{-1} + A^{+ \rm T} F \Big( I + \frac{1}{\alpha}FGGF\Big)^{-1}FA^+.
$$

Use Woodbury matrix identity again to get

$$
H(\alpha) =\alpha (AA^{\rm T})^{-1} + A^{+ \rm T} F \Big(   
I-FG \big( \alpha I + GFFG \big)^{-1} GF
\Big)FA^+.
$$

Take the limit as $\alpha \to 0$ and apply [the limit relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Limit_relations) to obtain

$$
(ABA^{\rm T})^{-1} = A^{+ \rm T} F \Big(   
I-FG \big( FG \big)^+
\Big)FA^+.
$$

Substitute $F$ and $G$ to get the final answer.

Comment: +1 This seems useful. Do you have a reference for this result?

Comment: @prdnr Hope it helps! This was my own derivation, which came from answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3747001/what-is-the-image-of-x-rm-tqx-le-1-under-a-linear-map-x-mapsto-cx). The [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3747001/what-is-the-image-of-x-rm-tqx-le-1-under-a-linear-map-x-mapsto-cx) is a more solid way to prove it.