# compute $C = AB^{-1}A^T$ without inverting B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, sparse-matrices

Is it possible to compute $C = AB^{-1}A^T$ without computing the inverse of $B$ explicitly? A is $n \times m$ matrix. B is $m \times m$ matrix ($m \gg n$). Thus $C$ is much smaller than $B$.

In the case where A is also $m \times m$ matrix and invertible, we can compute $C^{-1}$ with $A^{-T}BA^{-1}$ and then invert $C^{-1}$. However, when A is $n \times m$ ($m \gg n$), even though similar relationship still exists ( answered in [Inverse of product of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753695/inverse-of-product-of-matrices)), I did not find a way to compute it without computing inverse of $B$ explicitly.

The motivation for avoiding computation of $B^{-1}$ is that in my problem $B$ is a large sparse matrix, while its inverse is generally not sparse.

Comment: Does $A$ have any special structure or properties (symmetry, orthogonality, invertible. etc)?

Comment: @ja72 yes one property that can be assumed is that A is orthogonal or $AA^T$ is a diagonal matrix

Comment: Compute `D=solve(B,A^T)`, then `C=A*D`. A sparse solver usually does some kind of factorization and then either can trivially solve the systems for the factors, or applies some iterative method. This avoids establishing and computing the dense inverse, the factors themselves will be (almost) as sparse as $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding the inverse of $B$ is equivalent to finding, for each column of the identity matrix, the vector $v$ such that $Bv$ is equal to that column. To find $B^{-1}A^T$, you just need to find, for each column of $A^T$, a $v$ such that $Bv$ is equal to that column. Depending on your algorithms and your $B$, however, this might not be any faster.

Comment: LU factors of sparse matrices tend to be sparse. Inverses of sparse matrices tend to be dense. So au contraire, the «linsolve» approach will very likely be much more efficient. Not even mentioning the humongous reduction in the number of right hand sides.